# Cannot edit .tex file unless delete produced files

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker, texniccenter

I have just upgraded to `MiKTeX 2.9`from v2.8, where I was using TeXnic Center as my main tex editor.

Now I am trying to build a simple document to check if basic packages are loaded as well as test greek fonts, since my documents are in Greek.

My simple code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\begin{document}
        This is the first \LaTeX{} document!\\
        Το πρώτο κείμενο \LaTeX!\\
        Πάμε στην δεύτερη γραμμή!
\end{document}
```

The thing is that in order to change/edit something(either in the preamble or within `document` environment) I have to delete all produced files(excepr the `.pdf`). Unless I do so, the `pdflatex` in texmaker keeps building for ever. This behaviour remains the same also in TeXniC Center.

Has anyone seen something like that in `MikTeX 2.9`? How can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

`.aux` file

```
\relax 
\select@language{greek}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{greek}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{greek}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{greek}}
```

log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.9.6)  6 SEP 2013 16:31
entering extended mode
**LaTeX1.tex
(C:\Users\thanos\Desktop\LaTeX1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali
, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galic
ian, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian,
 kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman
-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, w
elsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
Language: english 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\greek.ldf"
Language: greek 2005/03/30 v1.3l Greek support from the babel system
 Loading the definitions for the Greek font encoding
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\lgrenc.def"
File: lgrenc.def 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Encoding
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\greek-inputenc\iso-8859-7.def"
File: iso-8859-7.def 2000/05/28 v1.2 Greek input encoding file
))
(C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\kerkis\kerkis.sty
File: kerkis.sty 2000/02/25 v1.5 Package `kerkis.sty'

*********************************************** ******** Loading The Kerkis FontFamily ********
********** Department of Mathematics ********** *********** University of the Aegean **********
***********************************************
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeX on input line 156.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeXe on input line 166.
)
No file LaTeX1.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LGR/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LGR+cmr on input line 6.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\lgrcmr.fd"
File: lgrcmr.fd 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Computer Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+mak on input line 6.

(C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\kerkis\ot1mak.fd)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/mak/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.99994pt on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LGR+mak on input line 6.

(C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\kerkis\lgrmak.fd)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `LGR/mak/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.99994pt on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/mak/m/sc' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.99994pt on input line 7.
 [1

{C:/Users/thanos/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (C:\Users\thanos\Desktop\LaTeX1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 833 strings out of 493921
 11820 string characters out of 3147280
 60064 words of memory out of 3000000
 4169 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6660 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,4n,20p,191b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/tha
nos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/kerkis/kerkis.enc}{C:/Users/thanos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/enc/d
vips/kerkis/gpkerkis.enc}<C:/Users/thanos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/kerkis/Kerkis-SmallCaps.pfb><C:/
Users/thanos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/kerkis/Kerkis.pfb>
Output written on LaTeX1.pdf (1 page, 22862 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

When build stops, in the build output windows in TXC, the message

```
*********************************************** ******** Loading The Kerkis FontFamily ********
********** Department of Mathematics ********** *********** University of the Aegean **********
***********************************************
```

stays there forever.

If I remove both kerkis and babel-inputenc then everything works fine! I also found out that if I remove babel-inputenc still everything works fine. It seems that babel is to blaim, but why?

Comment: Where is the document? Did you compile once on the command line? What does the log-file say?  Did you check if the aux-file is corrupted somehow?

Comment: The document is on Desktop and I compiled it through the editor's GUI. The `.aux` file doesn't seem corrupted. Please check my edited question to see both the log and aux file.

Comment: What happens if you remove all references to greek and also the kerkis-font from the document? Also can you show a log file of the second compilation (when the aux-file exists)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: If I remove both `kerkis` and `babel`-`inputenc` then everything works fine! I also found out that if I remove `babel`-`inputenc` still everything works fine. It seems that `babel` is to blaim, but why? Also if the `.aux` file pre-exists the log file is blank.

Comment: Can you put the tex.file somewhere in a zip-file for download? (So that I can test with your encoding?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Sure! Thank's so much! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19828093/LaTeX1.tex

Comment: This file doesn't load babel or inputenc (and it works without problems).

Comment: If you uncomment `babel` and `inputenc`? What if you compile it and then add a new line or edit it in any way?

Comment: If I uncomment (and save) I can't be sure that the encoding is preserved. But I tried and it works fine. I have a much newer lgrenc.def than you. Install the greek-fontenc package and try again.

Comment: `greek-inputenc` is already installed on my system...

Comment: But I wrote about greek-fontenc.

Comment: Oh pardon me! I cannot find it on the miktex package list. I found it in the ctan website(http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/greek/greek-fontenc) but I don't know which to download. I suppose the `xunicode-greek.sty` but how to use it? `\usepackage{greek-fontenc}`? `xudicode` is already installed, btw...

Comment: Synchronize the repository in the package manager to get an up-to-date package list. (Do it as user + as (admin)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I see... I tried to use `\usepackage{greek-fontenc}` but `it couldn't find the .sty package`. So I assumed it must be a package that doesn't need to be loaded. And I think it's working! At least with TXC! I must now try TeXMakeR as well! Thank's!

Comment: It's working there too! Thank you so much! Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Well in general I'm quite precise. When I write "install a package" this doesn't translate to "install and try to load" ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'll try to remember it next time! Thank you sooooo much for your help!

Comment: There is a known bug with Texnic Center.  If you tell MikTex to ask whether to install a package, it will crash.  Instead either tell it to always install or never install.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Actually I have told MiKTeX to install missing packages on the fly... without asking.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This bug was solved with version 2.0 of TXC.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with a package update.